# Generate heatmap using javascript to find which part of the webpage has maximum visitors

Tags: javascript, database, html, heatmap

I have a webpage and I have information in my database table about the windowWidth, windowHeight, mouse X, mouse Y, for all the hovers on the webpage, by different people who have visited the page.
The table gets updated real time, when people visit the website.

I want to generate a heatmap which would give a consolidated idea about the areas of the webpage where maximum number of people have hovered.

It becomes interesting because, the user could load this page from different devices, with different screen sizes, hence the window height and width and mouse x, mouse y and there by the aspect ratio would vary drastically.

winHeight varies from 194 to 2213. winWidth varies from 147 to 1349.

MouseX varies from 0 to 4168 and MouseY varies from 0 to 2607
How do I approach this. I dont want to use any paid tools out there.

Comment: Convert the absolute units to percentages

Comment: What is your actual problem though? You say you have screenwidth and screenheight, so just save it to the database and donsies right? Where does this problem you describe really a problem?

Comment: A quick Google search for `javascript heatmap library` found this: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Following would be the actual problem - 

I want to generate a heatmap which would give a consolidated idea about the areas of the webpage where maximum number of people have hovered.

It becomes interesting because, the user could load this page from different devices, with different screen sizes, hence the window height and width and mouse x, mouse y and there by the aspect ratio would vary drastically

Comment: @Stef No. that link shows realtime based on my activity. But i have a  table with information about so many users activity. i want a summary heatmap to see what part of the website many people hover over.

Comment: Gotcha. I misread. This one will take a data set: https://github.com/sunng87/heatcanvas. Demo: http://sunng.info/heatcanvas/

Comment: Maybe instead of storing the mouse x and y for each data row, store the DOM element ID on which the user is hovering/clicking